# redux: nested reducer access another store section

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use redux's combineReducers() helper function to combine two reducers like so:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  accounts: accountsReducer
})
```

I know each reducer can only modify a slice of the store it's assigned to, "user" and "accounts" in this case.

How can i modify the "user" part of my store from my accounts reducer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You can either listen to the same action in both reducers, or if you need to update the user state based on the update to the accounts' state, then you can use Redux thunks - https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

```
const action = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // dispatch action that accounts reducer listens to
  dispatch({
    type: 'SOME_ACTION'
  })

  // get the new accounts state
  let { accounts } = getState()

  // dispatch action that user reducer listens to, passing the new accounts state
  dispatch({
    type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION',
    payload: {
      accounts
    }
  })
}

// call with
dispatch(action())
```

Comment: " listen to the same action in both reducers" - does this mean i can do something like this: dispatch action like {type: 'SET_ACTIVE_ACCOUNT' , data: data} then in the accounts reducer handle the action to set active account and in the user reducer listen to the same event and modify some part of the store?

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu yes, every reducer is invoked when an action is dispatched. You can update multiple reducer's state from 1 action (provided you have all the data you need inside your action's payload)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. I think i read that somewhere. All reducers are called and their store outputs are merged.